# Extract map coordinate from Point Cloud data

Tags: 3d, gis, point-clouds, las

I am trying to render a map beneath the point cloud render view. I can see that other viewers render 2d maps beneath the point data rendered output.

I am not able to find what coordinates in the lat and long of a map can be rendered.

This is the header that I have in a file

[image]

Since the file is a COPC file, it has a couple of information more than the LAS/LAZ file.

Do you know if there is any way I can extract the map coordinate that needs to be rendered from this data?

Thank you in advance